# Django model location from a view

Tags: sql, django

In my `models.py` few models related to the different entities

```
class GuardSecurity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='GuardSecurity', editable=False)


class SecuredFaciliy(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='SecuredFaciliy', editable=False)
    facility_name=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    adress=models.CharField(max_length=64)

class License(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='License', editable=False)
    license_name=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    license_description=models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Equipment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Equipment', editable=False)
    equipment_name=models.CharField(max_length=64)

  
class AllEntity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table="entity_full_list"
```

They all in common have `UUID` as the primary key.
I implement an SQL view on those models

```
create view entity_full_list as
    select id, etype from entity_equipment
    union
    select id, etype from entity_guardsecurity
    union
    select id, etype from entity_license
    union
    select id, etype from entity_securedfaciliy
```

To solve the problem of finding a relevant model from a view table I added an `etype` column that points to the model (string that after can be translated to a command )

Is there another way to point to the exact model from my view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string in sql to avoid the extra column.

```
create view entity_full_list as
    select id, 'type' from entity_equipment
    union
    select id, 'type' from entity_guardsecurity
    union
    select id, 'type' from entity_license
    union
    select id, 'type' from entity_securedfaciliy
```

Comment: Any option to pass a model class instance to the sql view instead of just a string of a class name ?

Comment: One solution it would be to have a Django model for the general table and from the other models have a foreign key to that table. So using the django queries from the general table you access all the objects of the other tables using the related name. Relationships are explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/